# .Net Core Service writing to wrong event log

Tags: .net, .net-core, service, event-log

I've got a .net 3.1 core service and trying to write to a specific log file.  Instead of going to new log, the loginformations are attempting to write to the application log.
Getting:  "The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception.
Exception Info: System.AggregateException: An error occurred while writing to logger(s). (The source  is not registered in log 'Application'. (It is registered in log .) "

**The code to config in the createhostbuilder is**

```
    Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseWindowsService()
        .ConfigureLogging((context, logging) =>
        {
            logging.AddEventLog(new EventLogSettings()
            {
                SourceName = <my service name>,
                LogName = <custom log name>,
                Filter = (x, y) => y >= LogLevel.Information
            });
            logging.AddConsole();
        })

        .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
        {
            services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
        });
```

**Using ilogger and it's just a simple**
    _logger.LogInformation("my message");

Comment: Definitely appreciate feedback on this one!

Answer (score 1):

> "trying to write to a specific log file"

No, you're definitely not - the code you have shown is trying to write to the Windows Event Log using [Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Extensions.Logging.EventLog), writing to a source `<my service name>`.

Assuming that's what you want to do, rather than log to a file, the error message is explicit - the Event Log source you are specifying does not yet exist.

You have 2 options:

1. Create the Event Log source first. This requires admin permissions, and is typically done in the application installer (you can use `System.Diagnostics.EventLog.CreateEventSource`)
2. Don't specify a custom source and log name, using the defaults instead - that will mean your logs get written to the `Application` log, using the `".NET Runtime` source (which AFAIK is created when you install .NET`

Comment: Thanks Cocowalla... that's the rub.   I wanted them in the custom log I created.  Opened PS in admin and ran New-EventLog -LogName <customeventlog> -Source <service name in services>   WIthout the specifying my log in the setup I log fine to the Application Log, I really want to log to my customeventlog

Comment: OK, so it works as expected if you create the source first?

Comment: no. when I default to the appl log.. it does write there.  However, I want to write to a specific event log that I created (above).  By the  error message it appears that the addeventlog() and log creation are working, but the ILogger is not using that specific log (I think...)

Comment: Ah, I don't think `New-EventLog` lets you create custom logs - only custom *sources* within one of the standard logs (Application, System...)

Comment: Instead, you could use [eventcreate2](https://github.com/nbolton/eventcreate2) to create the custom log

Comment: I'll give that a try... much appreciated!

Comment: np, please do report back with the result!