# Exception Info: System.PlatformNotSupportedException: EventLog access is not supported on this platform

Tags: c#, .net-core, windows-services

I am getting the above mentioned error, when I tried to start the worker service on the target machine (windows server). I tried everything, but without any success. I am still getting the error.
I'm using .NET Core 3.1 and Microsoft.Extensions.Logging 7.0.0.
Here is the code, which causing the problem:

```
public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(x =>
                {
                    x.ClearProviders();
                    x.AddConsole();
                })
                .ConfigureServices((hostContext, services) =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<Worker>();
                })
                .UseWindowsService();
```

Hier some helpful links, which I have allready tried:

[Link1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56941898/how-to-setup-event-log-for-net-core-3-0-worker-service)
[Link2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60877765/how-do-i-enable-event-logging-in-a-net-core-workerservice-running-as-a-window-s)
[Link3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60044730/net-core-service-writing-to-wrong-event-log)

I will be greatful, if someone will be able to help me.

UPDATE:
I'm using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 7.0.0 and System.Diagnostics.EventLog 7.0.0. If I downgrade the packages to 6.0.0, it works.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Downgrading Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting 7.0.0 and System.Diagnostics.EventLog 7.0.0  to 6.0.0 seems to eliminate the problem

Comment: I wish I knew why this worked!

Comment: For me `Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility` with `7.0.0` was throwing this error. Downgrading to `6.0.0.` worked for me :)

Comment: I didn't have the time to investigate further. It was really interesting.

Answer (score 1):

Also had this with a mismatch in the .net framework version. Was running .net 5.0 and upgrading to 7 resolved the issue